# UI update with GET method

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I'm working on a project to get the api from openweathermap using node js & express & then update the UI.
I'm trying to update the UI of the page with the GET data, but it does not work. it prints undefined instead of the required values.

it works and gets the api from openweathermap on the terminal & console.

any help would be appreciated!

```
/* Global Variables */
const date = document.getElementById('date').value;
const temp = document.getElementById('temp').value;

// Create a new date instance dynamically with JS
let d = new Date();
let newDate = d.getMonth()+'.'+ d.getDate()+'.'+ d.getFullYear();

//baseURL & apiKey
const baseURL = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?zip=`;
const apiKey = `&appid=...`;

//event listener when user clicks generate button
const button = document.getElementById('generate');
button.addEventListener('click', performAction);

//event listener function
function performAction(event) {
  const zip = document.getElementById('zip').value;
  const feelings = document.getElementById('feelings').value;

  getData(baseURL, zip, apiKey)
    .then(function (data) {
      console.log(data);
      postData('/add', {date: newDate, temp: data.main.temp, feelings: feelings});
      updateUI();
})
};

//function to fetch api data
const getData = async (baseURL, zip, apiKey) => {
  const res = await fetch(baseURL+zip+apiKey)

  try {
    const data = await res.json();
    return data;
    console.log(data);
  }catch(error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}

// user input post data function
const postData = async (url = '', data = {}) => {
  const response = await fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'same-origin',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  });

  try {
    const newData = await response.json();
  }catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};

//updating UI
const updateUI = async () => {
  const request = await fetch('/all');
  try{
    const allData = await request.json();

    document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = allData.date;
    document.getElementById('temp').innerHTML = allData.temp;
    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = allData.content;

  }catch(error){
    console.log("error", error);
  }
}
```

Comment: Do not include `keys` or `credentials` here.

Comment: What do you see when you do `console.log(allData)`?

Comment: it's logging an empty object. and giving me this error (The deferred DOM Node could not be resolved into a valid node.)